# How to read multiple lines from a file until a blank line in PHP?

Tags: php, file

I am working with a log file that contains many lines. I want to use this log file in my dashboard. The file is in this format:

```
line1
line2
line3

line4
line5

line6
line7
line8
```

I want to read this file, and show its contents such as:

```
line1 line2 line3
line4 line5
line6 line7 line8
```

How can I do this in php?

Note: I can read the file and echo results in my dashboard. I just need the above function.

So far:

```
<php?>
$logs = File::get('logs.txt');
$lines=explode("\n", $logs);
echo $lines['0'];
```

but this shows me only the first line.

Comment: what did you attempt ? (show your code)

Comment: Just use an if statement to check the contents of each line. If it's empty, do something different. It's unclear if you've actually attempted to detect a blank line or what the issue is.

Comment: `this shows me only the first line`....use a loop, then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## METHOD ONE

Assuming that you use $xline as a temp buffer.

Looping over the log file , read one line at a time. (say use fgets)

Then concat the data read from the log to the temp buffer if the line read from the log is not blank, otherwise display the buffer, clear it and and  read the fresh line into the buffer

So the code is:

```
<?php
$xline="";

$handle = fopen("./logs.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
     while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
       if (trim($line)!=""){
           $xline.= " " . trim($line);
        }else{
           echo $xline."<br>";
           $xline=$line;
        }
   }
}
           echo $xline."<br>";
?>
```

Fully working example:

http://www.createchhk.com/SOanswers/SOanswer11Sep2022.php

Log file:

http://www.createchhk.com/SOanswers/logs.txt

## METHOD TWO

1. start with a `<div>` block as the buffer
2. Loop over the log file and use `</div><div>` to replace any blank line (else copy the line read to the buffer)
3. After the file is read , output the buffer and a `</div>`

So the code will be

```
<?php

$xline="<div>";

$handle = fopen("./logs2.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
     while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
       if (trim($line)!=""){
           $xline.=$line;
        }else{
           $xline.="</div><div>";
        }
   }
}

           echo $xline ."</div>"; 


?>
```

Fully working example:

http://www.createchhk.com/SOanswers/SOanswer11Sep2022b.php

Log file:

http://www.createchhk.com/SOanswers/logs2.txt

Comment: How do I loop this? to show each generated line in separated div?

Comment: Of course you may use <div>data</div>. My suggested answer just use <br> to separate adjacent lines but you may further amend to suit your needs

Comment: I just wanted to detect the blank line, and based on that, separate texts for each div.

Comment: Can I share my log file with you?

Comment: sure. please send me a link to download your log file

Comment: https://pastebin.com/cdGM3Y8g

Comment: Now in this file I want to show all the text in one div as a single line, until a blank lines appear. and then the second one in another, and so on.

Comment: Please see my revised answer (Method Two)